# Mvc.net Unit test with a nullable parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am new for unit test with Moq and Nunit. I have a simple unit test for getting a product list. But the test result didn't turn out as expected.

ProductManagementController action is:

```
       public ViewResult Index(int? id)
    {
        return View(_ProductRepo.GetProductList(id));
    }
```

ProductRepository is:

```
        public IList<Product> GetProductList(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return (db.Products).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return db.Products.Where(i => i.CategoryId == id).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I have two tests setup, but only the first test(get all products list) is fine.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test_ProductManagement
{
    private List<Product> products;
    private List<Category> categories;
    private Mock<IProductRepository> mockProducts; 
    private ProductManagementController target;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        images = new List<Product> {
           new Product{Id = 1, Name = "Boat", CategoryId = 1  },
           new Product{Id = 2, Name = "Picture Frame",CategoryId = 2 }
           };

        categories = new List<Category> {
            new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Outdoors" },
            new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Housewares" }
            };

        mockProducts = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        mockProducts.Setup(m => m.GetProductList(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(products);
        target = new ProductManagementController(mockProducts.Object);
    } 

    [Test]
    public void Index_Contains_All_Products()
    {
        //Action
        List<Product> result = ((IEnumerable<Product>)target.Index(It.IsAny<int>()).ViewData.Model).ToList();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual("Boat", result[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("Picture Frame", result[1].Name);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Index_Get_ImageList_By_CategoryId()
    {   //Arrange
        int id = 2;

        //Action
        List<Product> result = ((IEnumerable<Product>)target.Index(id).ViewData.Model).ToList();

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual("Picture Frame", result[0].Name);
    }
```

The 2nd test always return a full product list which include 2 products while I only expect 1 returned from `Assert.AreEqual(1,result.Count());`

I can't figure out why test code always take the id as a null parameter in the above index call: `target.Index(id)` . However all my project codes run correctly in the browsers.

Does anyone has a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out why test code always take the id as a null parameter in the above index call: target.Index(id)

It doesn't. You don't show all code (specifically how your controller handles the repository injection) and you seem to have renamed at least the `products` / `images` field, but the code works just fine.

You call `target.Index(id)`, which in turn calls `_ProductRepo.GetProductList(id)`. I assume this is your mock being called, which is `Setup()` by you to **always return the entire product list**.

The mock does exactly what you ask it to, no `ProductRepository` is used in this code, so your `if (id == null)` is never executed.

In order to fix this, you must `Setup()` your mock differently in each test method, or setup both cases in advance:

```
mockProducts.Setup(m => m.GetProductList(null)).Returns(products);
mockProducts.Setup(m => m.GetProductList(2)).Returns(new List<Product>{products[1]});
```

Of course you want to setup the latter call somewhat less specific, but I hope you see where you can fix this.

Comment: After setting up the mock separately, it works fine. Thank you for the explanation.